# Multiple Wi-Fi Services on Mac

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, network, wifi

At home, I have my own network. I have set up a DHCP fixed-address connection for that.

However, not all networks like that, and so I have set up another Service in Network preferences that just uses plain DHCP.

However, I can't set them to only connect to certain networks: changing settings in the Advanced window adjusts them for all Wi-Fi Services. This means I have both connections going.

How do I change the settings for just one Service, so I can set it to only connect to a certain network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the purpose of a Location. With only one Wi-Fi service, create a new location at the top of the window. Settings such as DHCP only apply to the currently selected location. Locations can be switched from this menu or from anywhere using the Apple menu once created.

[image]